# openWorldWithSpec making it impossible to return to previous windows

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, spec-ui, pharo-5

Reading the book "The Spec UI framework". Trying to implement the part described in chapter "Taking over the entire screen".

After executing the code suggested in the book:

```
WindowExample new openWorldWithSpec
```

it seems to be impossible to return to previous state. Tried to delete the new WorldMorph in the inspector. Also tried with halos, as the book suggests but those buttons that are available in the halo menu don't allow it to be closed.

Is it an intended behaviour for this (to be executed to prepare an end-user environment and disable programming UI) or am I missing something?

Working in Pharo 5.0, Mac OS X version.

Answer (score 1):

That is indeed intended behaviour, as part of making applications that do not allow access to the development environment anymore. But you can take a look at the code for PharoLauncher to see how you can enable a developer mode

Answer (score 0):

You can actually get back to normal by:

1. Alt-Ctrl-Clicking on the Morph (macOS combo may be different, this is for Windows).
2. Clicking on the little wrench and ask for inspect.
3. In the evaluation pane, do:

   self delete

World menu is available again.

Open a browser.
Done.

If one disables halos in settings, this is a tad harder.